# Simple recursion in LaTeX

Tags: recursion

I am trying to get into LaTeX recursion and created a command `\tower[2][3][4][2]` that returns a [power tower](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/power_tower), `2^{3^{4^2}}`, for any number of arguments. My attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\tower{o}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\towerstep{#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\towerstep{m}{%
   #1^\tower}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \tower[2][3][4][2]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces a lot of errors, but it gives the correct output. The errors come from the expression not standing in mathmode (adding `$` made things worse for me) and from missing braces. I suppose this has something to do with the order in which commands are expanded. How can I fix the code?

Comment: Does the syntax absolutely have to be `\tower[2][3][4][2]`? Would `\tower{2,3,4,2}` be an acceptable input format?

Comment: Why are trying to do this? To learn how tex works or is there some practical purpose behind this?

Comment: Just for learning. I would prefer not giving a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution in the spirit of the programmation by continuation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \towerAux { m o }
  {
    \IfValueTF { #2 }
      { \towerAux {{#1}{#2}} }
      { \__tower:nn {#1} { } }
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__tower:nn #1 #2 
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
      { #2 }
      { \__tower_i:nnn #1 { #2 } }
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__tower_i:nnn #1 #2 #3 { \__tower:nn { #1 } { #2 ^ { #3 } } }

\NewDocumentCommand \tower { } { \towerAux { } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\tower[5][3][4][2]$
\end{document}
```

With this programmation, `$\tower[5][3][4][2]$` is replaced successively by the following instructions:

```
$\tower[5][3][4][2]$

$\towerAux{}[5][3][4][2]$

$\towerAux{{}{5}}[3][4][2]$

$\towerAux{{{}{5}}{3}}[4][2]$

$\towerAux{{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}}[2]$

$\towerAux{{{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}}{2}}$
```

As you see, `\towerAux` is recursive.

Now, all the arguments (if I can say) have been structured in a kind of list and the last one is the first accessible. You can now construct the required result in a kind of auxiliary argument (at the end) as usual in recursive programmation. The commands `\__tower:nn` and `\__tower_i:nnn` are mutually recursive.

```
$\__tower:nn{{{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}}{2}}{}$

$\__tower_i:nnn{{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}}{2}{}$

$\__tower:nn{{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}}{2^{}}$

$\__tower_i:nnn{{{}{5}}{3}}{4}{2^{}}$

$\__tower:nn{{{}{5}}{3}}{4^{2^{}}}$

$\__tower_i:nnn{{}{5}}{3}{4^{2^{}}}$

$\__tower:nn{{}{5}}{3^{4^{2^{}}}}$

$\__tower_i:nnn{}{5}{3^{4^{2^{}}}}$

$\__tower_i:nnn{}{5^{3^{4^{2^{}}}}}$

$5^{3^{4^{2^{}}}}$
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use the same approach to generate a "tensor tower"? Using the package tensor I can create \tensor{T}{^a^b_c_d} for example. Then I might want to build a tensor of a tensor, so using package physics I might write \tensor{\qty(\tensor{T}{^a^b_c_d})}{^e_f}. In the same way I could go on and create next \tensor{\qty(\tensor{\qty(\tensor{T}{^a^b_c_d})}{^e_f})}{^g_h_i}. The whole thing gets messy but if there was a command like \tensorgroup{T}{a:b,c:d//e,f//g,h:i} then the whole thing is much easier to write.

Comment: @TedBlack: You should ask another question because it's not possible to answer your question in a comment.

Comment: No problem I have already done so. I think the penultimate line is \__tower:nn and not \__tower_i:nnn Thanks for your answer I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tower{\@ifnextchar[{\def\endtower{}\towerstep}{}}%
\def\towerstep[#1]{#1%
  \@ifnextchar[{\edef\endtower{\endtower\egroup}^\bgroup\towerstep}{\endtower}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
        $\tower[2][3][4][2]$ 
        $\tower[2][3][4]$ 
        $\tower[2][3]$ 
        $\tower[2]$ 
        $\tower$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I build two token lists, the first containing

```
{1^{2^{3^{4^{5^{6^{7
```

and the other containing

```
}}}}}}}
```

Actually, the braces are stored as `\c_group_begin_token` and `\c_group_end_token`, so the token lists are balanced.

If `[` follows, a further step is taken. At the end, the two lists are delivered.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tower}{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__perner_tower_left_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__perner_tower_right_tl
  \perner_tower_build:n { }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__perner_tower_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__perner_tower_right_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \perner_tower_build:n
 {
  \peek_charcode:NTF [
   {% there is a [
    \__perner_tower_add:nw { #1 }
   }
   {% no [, end
    \__perner_tower_end:
   }
 }
    
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__perner_tower_add:nw #1 [#2]
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__perner_tower_left_tl { #1 \c_group_begin_token #2 }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__perner_tower_right_tl { \c_group_end_token }
  \perner_tower_build:n { \c_math_superscript_token }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__perner_tower_end:
 {
  \tl_use:N \l__perner_tower_left_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__perner_tower_right_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\tower[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]$

\end{document}
```

Much shorter with a different syntax. The argument is split at commas; then between any two items we output `^{` (again as implicit tokens) and at the end the right number of `}` is output.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tower}{m}
 {
  \perner_tower_build:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__perner_tower_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \perner_tower_build:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__perner_tower_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__perner_tower_seq { \c_math_superscript_token \c_group_begin_token }
  \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__perner_tower_seq - 1 } { \c_group_end_token }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\tower{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically, your `\tower` macro expands into `2^3^4^2`, and not into `$2^{3^{4^{2}}}$`, so there are two types of errors: missing math mode delimiter (`^` makes sense only in math mode), and double superscript (TeX deliberately throws error for `$a^b^c$` and doesn't try to guess which is correct, `${a^b}^c$ or $a^{b^c}$).

The problem with the code is that it should somehow collect all these `}}}` and put them at the end of the expansion. The following code does just that (I also put `$$` for math mode):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\tower{}{\def\endtower{}\starttower}
\NewDocumentCommand\starttower{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\edef\endtower{\endtower\egroup}\towerstep{#1}}{\endtower}}
\NewDocumentCommand\towerstep{m}{%
  #1^\bgroup\starttower}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $\tower[2][3][4][2]$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\endtower` macro which is empty initially, but every time `\starttower` executes and finds an optional argument (the next tower floor), it extends by another `\egroup`. `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are equivalent to `{` and `}` respectively, and they are easier to use in macro definitions in case if nonmatching braces are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% In case there is an optional argument \tower calls \towerreverseloop:
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\tower{o}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\towerreverseloop{[{#1}]}}%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \towerreverseloop reverses the order of the list of optional arguments.
% #1 holds the reversed list of optional arguments gathered so far.
% #2 is the next optional argument.
% If there are no more optional arguments to put into reversed order, 
% then \towerinitializeconstructexpressionloop is applied to the reversed
% list of optional arguments gathered so far.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\towerreverseloop{mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \towerreverseloop{[{#2}]#1}%
  }{%
    \towerinitializeconstructexpressionloop#1%
  }%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \towerinitializeconstructexpressionloop calls \towerconstructexpressionloop,
% hereby initializing \towerconstructexpressionloop's "expression constructed
% so far"-argument with the first element of the reversed list of optional
% arguments.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\towerinitializeconstructexpressionloop{o}{%
  \towerconstructexpressionloop{#1}%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \towerconstructexpressionloop constructs the desired expression from the
% elements of the reversed list of optional arguments.
% #1 holds the expression constructed so far.
% #2 next optional argument/next element of the reversed list of
%    optional arguments.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\towerconstructexpressionloop{mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}%
            {\towerconstructexpressionloop{#2^{#1}}}%
            {#1%
             %\def\result{#1}\show\result
            }%
}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \verb|$\tower[2][3][4][2]$|: $\tower[2][3][4][2]$\\
        \verb|$\tower[2][3][4]$|: $\tower[2][3][4]$\\
        \verb|$\tower[2][3]$|: $\tower[2][3]$\\
        \verb|$\tower[2]$|: $\tower[2]$\\
        \verb|$\tower$|: $\tower$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]